# How to display devise current_user's last uploaded paperclip image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, paperclip

I have a dashboard set up to have the last upload by the current_user (devise helper) displayed, however the last upload regardless of who current_user is shows up.

dashboards controller:

```
class DashboardsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @todo_lists = current_user.todo_lists
    @paperclip_image = PaperclipImage.last
    @paperclip_image.user = current_user
  end
end
```

paperclip_image model:

```
class PaperclipImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_attached_file :asset, styles: {
    medium: "300x300>",
    small: "140x140>",
    thumb: "60x64!"
  }

  validates_attachment_content_type :asset, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

end
```

user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :todo_lists
  has_many :todo_items
  has_many :paperclip_images
end
```

dashboards index.html.erb

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <h3> Latest Prototype </h3>
    <%= link_to image_tag(@paperclip_image.asset.url(:medium), class: "img-thumbnail"), @paperclip_image.asset.url %>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <p class="paperclip-images-icons">
            <%= link_to image_tag("edit.png", :alt => "Reupload Image", :title => "Reupload Image"), edit_paperclip_image_path(@paperclip_image) %>
            <%= link_to image_tag("list.png", :alt => "See All Images", :title => "See All Images"), paperclip_images_path %>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

gems installed:

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.0'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.1'
gem 'devise'
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are getting the most recent PaperclipImage with

```
@paperclip_image = PaperclipImage.last
```

and with your line

```
@paperclip_image.user = current_user
```

You are saying, OK with the last `PaperclipImage` I want to assign it's user to the current_user. And that's exactly what would happen if you added the line `@paperclip_image.save!`

You'll have to find the current_user's last `PaperclipImage`

Something **along the lines** of:

```
@paperclip_image = current_user.paperclip_images.last
```

so the whole `Index Action` should look like this:

```
def index
  @todo_lists = current_user.todo_lists
  @paperclip_image = current_user.paperclip_images.last
end
```

Comment: Ahhh- I did that before but I was getting an error but now that you've confirmed this solution, I checked again and it looks like the error was related to the user not having any images so I actually had it right but just needed to fix the exception. Thank you so much!